# How to increase image review time on a Canon T5i?

Tags: canon, preview, image-review

How do I get pictures I have taken to have a longer review time on my monitor? And I am having trouble reviewing all of the pictures I have taken on my Canon T5i.

Comment: Don't review them on the camera monitor, other than a quick "Yup, looks like I got that one".  Many cameras let you set the monitor timeout.  Check your owner's manual.

Comment: also, what do you mean exactly by "I am having trouble reviewing all of the pictures I have taken"? Users here can help you if you are more specific

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean that pictures show up for only few seconds on your camera's LCD after you snapped them.

First of all, you can view images for a very long time by pressing "Playback" button and scroll through images by using cross key (the one with left-right/up-down buttons).

Also, you can set how long the image is displayed on the LCD monitor immediately after capture. Consult page 204 of [the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300010905/02/eos-rebelt5i-700d-im2-en.pdf)

[image]

Finally, you should read your camera manual before asking more camera-usage related questions.